# Bootstrap Passing Data to a Modal

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I have read the Bootsrap documentation and even tested their "Varying modal content based on trigger button" example, but that doesn't work.

Any idea on how can I pass a data to a modal so that I will not create multiple modals in my page.

Here is the button that triggers the modal:

```
<a class="btn btn-danger" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#deleteSubject" data-whatever="<?= $subj_id ?>" role="button" title="Delete Subject"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash" aria-hidden="true"></span></a>
```

And here is the modal:

```
<div class="modal fade" id="deleteSubject" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="deleteSubjectLabel">
          <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
            <div class="modal-content">
                <form action="#" method="post">
                  <div class="modal-header">
                    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
                    <h4 class="modal-title" id="deleteSubjectLabel">Delete Subject</h4>
                  </div>
                  <div class="modal-body">
                    <h4>Do you want to delete this subject?</h4>
                    <input type="text" id="subjid" name="subjid">
                  </div>
                  <div class="modal-footer">
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Cancel</button>
                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-danger">Delete</button>
                  </div>
                </form>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
```

And here is the javascript:

```
<script>
        $('#deleteSubject').on('show.bs.modal', function (event) {
          var button = $(event.relatedTarget)
          var subjId = button.data('whatever')
          var modal = $(this)
          modal.find('.modal-body input').val(subjId)
        })
    </script>
```

I also tried the `show.bs.modal` but nothing happens. I tried to create a separate script to test if the `$subj_id` is being read through the use of `alert` but it works.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you need to wrap the code in a document ready and since your input is named and has an id - target it directly and then you wont need the find either:

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $('#deleteSubject').on('show.bs.modal', function (event) {
          var button = $(event.relatedTarget);
          var subjId = button.data('whatever');
          $('#subjid').val(subjId);
        })
    })
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you forgot the `$` on your modal instance , it should be `$modal`

```
 <script>
        $('#deleteSubject').on('show.bs.modal', function (event) {
          var button = $(event.relatedTarget)
          var subjId = button.data('whatever')
          var $modal = $(this)
          $modal.find('.modal-body input').val(subjId)
        })
    </script>
```

Comment: The dollar sign in the variable name `$modal` makes no difference. May want to delete this before you're downvoted.

Answer (score -1):

Simply set the value of input subjid using JavaScript / jQuery during the on click event.

```
$('#subjid').val(*value*);
```